# Airflow PostgresOperator Safety -- execution_timeout not respected? How to kill process in DB if it's taking too long?

Tags: postgresql, airflow

Working on getting Airflow implemented at my company but need to perform some safety checks prior to connecting to our prod dbs.
There is concern about stupid SQL being deployed and eating up too many resources. My thought was that an `execution_timeout` setting on a PostgresOp task would:

1. Fail the task
2. Kill the query process in the db

I have found neither to be true.

Code:

```
with DAG(
    # Arguments applied to instantiate this DAG. Update your values here
    # All parameters visible in airflow.models.dag
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=['admin'],
    max_active_runs=1
) as dag:

    kill_test = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="kill_test",
        execution_timeout=timedelta(seconds=10),
        postgres_conn_id="usa_db",
        sql="""
SET application_name to airflow_test;
<SELECT... intentionally long running query> ;
        """)
```

Airflow does not fail the task after the timeout.
Even when I manually fail the task in the UI, it does not kill the query in the Postgres db.
What is the deal here? Is there any way to put in safety measures to hard kill an Airflow initiated Postgres query in the db?

I'm not posting here, but I have checked:

1. Airflow UI shows task instance duration way over execution timeout
2. pg_stat activity to confirm query is running way over execution timeout

Comment: I don't know what is airflow.  How to kill process in DB if it's taking too long? >>>
There is `client_connection_check_interval` :  Sets the time interval between checks for disconnection while running queries. in PostgreSQL14, `idle_session_timeout`: Sets the maximum allowed idle time between queries, when not in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this parameter `runtime_parameters={'statement_timeout': '180000ms'}`.([airflow example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html#the-complete-postgres-operator-dag))

I don't know in which version this was added but if you update your `apache-airflow-providers-postgres` module to the last version you can use the mentioned parameter.